# Error with SQLite query, What am I missing?

Tags: sqlite

I've been attempting to increase my knowledge and trying out some challenges. I've been going at this for a solid two weeks now finished most of the challenge but this one part remains. The error is shown below, what am i not understanding?

Error in sqlite query: `update users set last_browser= 'mozilla' + select sql from sqlite_master'', last_time= '13-04-2019' where id = '14'`

edited for clarity:

I'm trying a CTF challenge and I'm completely new to this kind of thing so I'm learning as I go. There is a login page with test credentials we can use for obtaining many of the flags. I have obtained most of the flags and this is the last one that remains.

After I login on the webapp with the provided test credentials, the following messages appear: [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWBBq.png)

The question for the flag is "What value is hidden in the database table secret?"

So from the previous image, I have attempted to use sql injection to obtain value. This is done by using burp suite and attempting to inject through the user-agent.
I have gone through trying to use many variants of the injection attempt shown above. Im struggling to find out where I am going wrong, especially since the second single-quote is added automatically in the query. I've gone through the sqlite documentation and examples of sql injection, but I cannot sem to understand what I am doing wrong or how to get that to work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] by showing a few lines of `create ...` and `insert ...`. Then explain more about what this is supposed to do. If possible show desired result in contrast to the one you get. What looks like you intended to post an error message looks more like a code quote. Showing both would be helpful. Explain your reasoning behind your attempt. In short: Show, explain, quote, provide, ... much more.

Comment: "injection through user-agent post logon it will bring up last logged on by "date" and "browser info"." this might be the least clear part of you post. Try to rephrase. Make sure that the end of the quote is obvious. Maybe you will find helpful options here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I don't understand the sqlite_master part. That's the metadata table, containing the names and definitions of tables, views, and some other things. Why do you want to concatenate it to 'mozilla'?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery such as `select sql from sqlite_master` should be enclosed in brackets.

So you'd want

```
update user set last_browser= 'mozilla' + (select sql from sqlite_master''), last_time= '13-04-2019' where id = '14';
```

Although I don't think that will achieve what you want, which isn't clear. A simple test results in :-

[image]

You may want a concatenation of the strings, so instead of `+` use **`||`**. e.g.

```
update user set last_browser= 'mozilla' || (select sql from sqlite_master''), last_time= '13-04-2019' where id = '14';
```

In which case you'd get something like :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's input, I've worked this out.

The sql query was set up like this:

```
update users set last_browser= '$user-agent', last_time= '$current_date' where id = '$id_of_user'
```

edited user-agent with burp suite to be:

```
Mozilla', last_browser=(select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' limit 0,1), last_time='13-04-2019
```

Iterated with that found all tables and columns and flags. Rather time consuming but could not find a way to optimise.